# Avro "long" type's maximum value

Tags: avro

I have an type which is "long" in my avro schema file (avsc) like the below snippet

```
{
        "name" : "TransactionDateTime",
        "type" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "logicalType" : "timestamp-micros"
        },
        "doc" : "Transaction Time To UTC",
        "default" : 32503679999999000
      },
```

When I tried publishing this to my confluent schema registry (running in docker), i am getting an error

```
invalid "long": 32503679999999000
```

if I change it to 32400000000, it works fine. This makes me think, it is just that the schema registry on my docker instance can only handle 32 bit "longs" and not 64 Bit.

Any pointers on how to get around this error, like a setting in kafka server.properties or something?

Edit : I am able to publish the schema with the original long using java code. So narrowed down the problem to the GUI where I try to evolve the schema.

```
docker info
===============
Client:
 Version:    24.0.5
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.11.2-desktop.1
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-buildx.exe
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.20.2-desktop.1
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-compose.exe
  dev: Docker Dev Environments (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.1.0
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-dev.exe
  extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.2.20
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-extension.exe
  init: Creates Docker-related starter files for your project (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.1.0-beta.6
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-init.exe
  sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc.)
    Version:  0.6.0
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-sbom.exe
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.26.0
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-scan.exe
  scout: Command line tool for Docker Scout (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  0.20.0
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-scout.exe

Server:
 Containers: 9
  Running: 9
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 10
 Server Version: 24.0.5
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
 runc version: v1.1.7-0-g860f061
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: unconfined
 Kernel Version: 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 15.45GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: 283fff09-0cef-4434-b061-3e9e1c29c387
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 HTTP Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 No Proxy: hubproxy.docker.internal
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  hubproxy.docker.internal:5555
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_iops_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_iops_device support
WARNING: daemon is not using the default seccomp profile
```

Comment: Docker shouldn't matter (run your Schema Registry outside of it and test again), the Docker containers are `linux/amd64` or `linux/arm64` builds, therefore the JVM runs 64 bit as well... Says right in the docs, 64-bit https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/#primitive-types ; There is nothing in the Kafka server properties that'll affect Avro SDK or the Schema Registry settings

Comment: Can you provide the output of `$ docker info` somewhere?